# msg.content not being defined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Okay so I am trying to make an announcement command for my server, but when I try to run this it says: **ReferenceError: msg is not defined**

I am not sure on what it is that I am doing incorrectly.

Here is the code in question:

```
'use strict';
//require discord.js package
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json")

//Create an instance of a Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

//The ready event is vital, only after this will your bot start reacting and responding
client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('I am ready!');
});

//create an event listener for messages
client.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content === 'ping') {
     message.channel.send('pong');
 }
});

if (msg.content === "^ann"){
 let channel = client.channels.cache.get('channel id');
 msg.channel.send("What is your announcement? (^cancel to cancel)");
const collector = msg.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id, { time: 100000000 });
collector.once('collect', m => {
if (m.content == "^cancel") {
              m.author.send("Announcement cancelled.");
               return;
             } else {
         var announcement = m.content;

         channel.send(announcement);
         msg.channel.send("Announcement made!");
         return;
             }
});

//Do stuff
client.on("message", function (msg) {
 if (msg.content.indexOf("^mirror") === 0) {
     let item = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     
     .setImage(msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
     .setColor("#E6E6FA")
     .setFooter("OMG! WHEW~");
     

     msg.channel.send(item);
 }
})




//Bot Token
client.login('token')}
```

This is what i have for the code that I am working on

Comment: You need to show more code. More specifically how you are generating the `msg` variable since the error says that variable is undefined.

Comment: Okay I will edit my post

Comment: Your code is outside of a `client.on("message", `.

Comment: ooh I can't believe I missed that omg thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you have your code outside the message event. So all the code about the message etc. has to be in the message event.

The second thing, I suggest to create 1 message event. I see you have created 2 message events. That is not a big problem, but it will clean your code en is more effective. Now, if someone sends a message, he will check this message 2 times. I hope I made it a little bit clear!